# Errors Fatal Exception on Two activities

Tags: android

```
enter code here

  05-31 00:26:46.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yaraby.y/yaraby.y.yarab}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at a ndroid.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at yaraby.y.yarab.onCreate(yarab.java:92)
 05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
  05-31 00:32:08.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4301):     ... 11 more
```

Yaraby Code

```
enter code here
 public class yaraby extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String sentence,sentence1, modifiedSentence;;
EditText inputfld, txt;
TextView Text;
Button Enter, Connect, next;
Socket clientSocket;

DataOutputStream outToServer;
BufferedReader inFromServer ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inputfld=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    Text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
    Enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    Connect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);

    Text.append( "\n about to create a socket");    


    txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);   

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                Text.append("PPPPP");
            Intent i = new Intent(yaraby.this, yarab.class);

            startActivity(i);
            Text.append("OPS");
            }
            catch(Error e){
                Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", e.getMessage());
                Text.append("ofa7ay");
            }

        }});

                  }






public void appendText(View view){
    Text.append( "\n  In chat ");

    try{


    sentence=inputfld.getText().toString();
    sentence1="ingyyyy";
    Text.append( "\n  DataStream creating");        
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); 
    Text.append(modifiedSentence);
    inputfld.setText(null);

    }
    catch(Exception modifiedsentence){
        Text.append("Exception");
    }


}


public void connect(View view){
    try{
        clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.1.6",54611); 
        Text.append( "\n created a socket");
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        Text.append( "\n created a datastream");
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        Text.append( "\n created a bufferReader");
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());



    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
   }
```

yarab code

```
enter code here
package yaraby.y;

           public class yarab extends MapActivity

   {
Socket clientSocket;
TextView Text; 
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
DataOutputStream outToServer;            
BufferedReader inFromServer ;
 Button start;
int error = 50;
GeoPoint p, p2;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable, drawable2;
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay, itemizedOverlay2;

LocationManager locationManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, mlocListener);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);






        mc = mapView.getController();

        mc.setZoom(12);
        addOverLays();
          start= (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);   


                }

public void addOverLays() {
    String[] coordinates = { "31.216487288475037", "29.932637214660645",
            "30.084123015403748", "51.5002", "-0.1262",
            "31.337149143218994" };

    double lat = 29.98739718380868, lat2 = 29.987810254096985;
    double log = 31.442527770886084, log2 = 31.44258677959442;
    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
    p2 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat2 * 1E6 ), (int) (log2 * 1E6 ));
    p3 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
    p4 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat4 * 1e6), (int) (log4 * 1e6));
    p5 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat14* 1e6), (int) (log14 * 1e6));
    p6 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat8 * 1e6), (int) (log8 * 1e6));
    p7 = new GeoPoint((int) (t1* 1e6), (int) (log15 * 1e6));
    p8 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat5 * 1e6), (int) (log5 * 1e6));
    p9 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat6 * 1e6), (int) (log6 * 1e6));
    p10=new GeoPoint( (int) (t4 * 1e6), (int) (log12 * 1e6));
    p11=new GeoPoint( (int) (t2* 1e6), (int) (log14 * 1e6));
    p12=new GeoPoint( (int) (t3* 1e6), (int) (log5 * 1e6));
    p13=new GeoPoint( (int) (t5* 1e6), (int) (log12 * 1e6));
    p14=new GeoPoint( (int) (t6* 1e6), (int) (log11 * 1e6));
    p15=new GeoPoint( (int) ((t6+t1)/2* 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
    p15=new GeoPoint( (int) (t3* 1e6), (int) (log11 * 1e6));
    p16=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat15* 1e6), (int) (log15 * 1e6));
    p17=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat13* 1e6), (int) (log13 * 1e6));
    p18=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat9* 1e6), (int) (log9 * 1e6));
    p19=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat10* 1e6), (int) (log10 * 1e6));
    p20=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat11* 1e6), (int) (log11 * 1e6));
    p21=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat12* 1e6), (int) (log12 * 1e6));
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wit);
    drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);

    itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2, this);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
    OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");


    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);


    mc.setZoom(17);



}





public void Location(){



    LocationManager myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    LocationListener mlocListener1 = new MyLocationListener();

    LocationManager mlocManager1 = null;
    mlocManager1.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, mlocListener1);
        //  Get the current location in start-up
          GeoPoint initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
       .getLatitude()*1000000),(int)(myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude()*1000000));
       mc.animateTo(initGeoPoint);
    mc.setZoom(16);

    drawable21 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ggg);
    itemizedOverlay21 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable21,this);
    OverlayItem over21 = new OverlayItem(initGeoPoint, "offff", "over21");

    itemizedOverlay21.addOverlay(over21);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay21);
}


/* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));



        String Text = "My current location is: " +

        "Latitud =" + loc.getLatitude()+ 

        "Longitud =" +loc.getLongitude() ;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

        Text,

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    mc.animateTo(point);


    }


    private Resources getResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

        "Gps Disabled",

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

        "Gps Enabled",

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

    {

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}/* End of Class MyLocationListener */

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

           }
```

Comment: I see that `setContentView()` is called with the same resource identifier (R.layout.main) in both cases, did you really mean to do that? Other than that, it's kinda hard to know what the code in line 92 is specifically.

Comment: You must put this as an answer because it work wiz me :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 92 of `yarab.java`, in your `onCreate()` method. Based on the comment by @dmon, my guess is that you are loading the wrong layout and therefore your attempt to retrieve your `MapView` fails. However, that is just a guess, since you did not tell us what line 92 of `yarab.java` actually is.

Comment: could you belive this is line 92 !!